# Não abrir mais de um form ao mesmo tempo em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que e praticamente um CRUD.

O meu problema e o seguinte: quando eu abro uma tela do meu sistema, se eu clicar no menu para abrir novamente, fica com duas janelas abertas, ou seja, se eu clicar varias vezes no menu ficara com varias janelas abertas.

Eu gostaria de saber como que eu faço para o sistema não permitir que abra mais de uma janela no sistema ao mesmo tempo? Só permitir abrir uma de cada vez.

o meu form principal que contém o menu é o pai dos outros form.

e os demais form abrem dentro do MDIParent

Comment: Como os forms são abertos? Dentro de um MDIParent?

Comment: Edite a pergunta para informar que usa formulário pai.

Comment: [Veja esta solução](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018272/preventing-multiple-instance-of-one-form-from-displaying) pode ser que seja do mesmo genéro que a sua! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo o que encontrei pesquisando, não é possível abrir um form `mdi` filho como `dialog`.

Você tem duas opções:

1. Não "setar" o form filho como `mdi child` e tratá-lo como um form normal. Assim você consegue abrir com `.ShowDialog()`;
2. Usar [esse mini framework](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48436/MDI-child-as-dialog-form-MDI-modal-workaround) para fazer o form filho abrir com dialog de forma alternativa;

Comment: valeu deu certinho

Answer (score 0):

**Usando singleton:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
 .....
 private static Form2 inst;
 public static Form2  GetForm
 {
   get
    {
     if (inst == null || inst.IsDisposed)
         inst = new Form2();
     return inst;
     }
 }
 ....
}
Invoke/Show this form,

Form2.GetForm.Show();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp

**Encontrei essa solução na net:**

```
frm2 f = Application.OpenForms["NameOfForm2"];
if(f != null)
   f.BringToFront();
else
{
   frm2 f = new frm2();
   f.Show();
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080083/how-to-prevent-my-program-to-open-the-same-window-form-twice

Ou veja no exemplo abaixo onde eu verifico se o outlook está rodando antes de iniciá-lo. Pode fazer uma verificação desse tipo no construtor da sua tela.

```
//Se não estiver iniciado, inicia uma instância do outlook
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count().Equals(0))
{
    Process.Start("outlook.exe");//Aqui continue seu código normalmente
}
else
{
   //Cancele o processo
   Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hermano na boa, abre o form dessa maneira:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = frmNomeDoSeuForm.ShowDialog();
```

Mas tenho uma dica, como hoje as necessidades de que os sistemas sejam multitelas seria interessante você apenas verificar se aquele mesmo form já está aberto... se sim deixá-lo em primeiro plano e em foco.... assim você pode deixar em outra tela outra parte do sistema... veja é simples...

```
        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmNomeDoForm>().Count() > 0)
        {
            Application.OpenForms.OfType<FrmNomeDoForm>().First().Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            FrmNomeDoForm frmNomeDoForm = new FrmNomeDoForm();
            frmNomeDoForm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: ok! estamos aqui pra isso! abraço amigos! espero que possa ajudar!

Comment: Eu ainda removeria a linguagem fática usada, mas creio que realmente esteja responda à pergunta agora

Answer (score 0):

Também estava com essa dúvida. Segui a dica do Tiago de Abreu e deu certo.
Segue código final:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCad_Categoria>().Count() > 0)
{
    Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmCad_Categoria>().First().Focus();
}
else
{
    frmCad_Categoria form = new frmCad_Categoria();
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
}
```